# phpmailer sending mail

Tags: php, attachment, sendmail, phpmailer

I am using phpmailer class to send email and i am attaching a file to the mail.
The email is sent successfully but the attachment which is an sql file is empty which should not be the case. I have tried with an image file, but it seems that every file that i attach is empty.
Can anyone help me solve this problem please?

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
    $body = "Reminder";
    $mail->IsSMTP();  
    $mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com";  
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;  

    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;  
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";  
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";  
    $mail->Port = 465;  
    $mail->Username = "abc@gmail.com";  
    $mail->Password = "abc";              
   $mail->SetFrom('abc@gmail.com',
  'blbla');
   $mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");
   $mail->Subject = "Your order has been successfully placed"
   $mail->MsgHTML($body);
   $mail->AddAddress("xyz@live.com","xyz");
   $mail->AddAttachment("D:\b2\shop3.sql","shop3.sql");
```

UPDATE: I have tried to display the size of the file before attaching it, and it actually displays the file size. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You could try testing the existence of the file before trying to attach it. Also, it's unknown how a `\` is going to act inside of a string in PHP, so it's best practice to escape it via C standards:

```
$attach_filename = "D:\\b2\\shop3.sql";
if (is_file($attach_filename)) {
    $mail->AddAttachment($attach_filename,"shop3.sql");
} else {
    print "error: attachment $attach_filename doesn't exist";
}
```

Comment: @amphetamachine: The mail is sent successfully with shop3.sql attached but it is empty.
No error message is displayed.

Comment: Yes, but your PHP coding tells PHPMailer to name the attachment "shop3.sql". That is not to say that it actually find the "D:\b2\shop2.sql" file to attach, but may instead be naming an empty/non-existent/inaccessible file's contents as "shop3.sql".

Would the standard PHPMailer set display an error message if the attachment does not exist? I just had a look at the PHP code, and `$mail->AddAttachment()` should return false in the event of the file being unreadable. Maybe you should see what it returns when executed and, if false, abort the email and show the Error Message.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions for further testing:

1 - Try and attach a simple *.txt file located in the same directory as the script being executed. This will test the Attachment side of things, and may prove whether the script is either not liking attaching any files, or just the *.sql one.

2 - If #1 works OK, move the *.txt file into the same folder which the *.sql one currently resides in, then test again. This should then prove whether the script is able to access a file via the filepath you are using.

3 - Try echoing the contents of the *.sql file, either into the web-browser output generated by the script, or into the body of the email message. This should also prove whether the script is able to read the file in question.

I may be waaaay off base with these suggestions, but they would be where I would start if I were to try and troubleshoot this one.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to try swiftmailer.org instead

Comment: -1 - Number one rule of answering questions: never suggest a complete rewrite unless absolutely necessary. Besides, PHPMailer works well enough.

Answer (score -1):

This may help you instead.
What I've done is first zipped the .sql file to make sure all the content is included and to make the email smaller (useful if you have a database of 10MB or more)
I use a .sh script to do this which i named "sqlbackup.sh":

side note: my .sql file is stored under the folder "db_backup/sqldata" on the webserver and is the only .sql file in this folder. Create the two folders if they don't already exist.

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/<username>/db_backup/sqldata/
tar -zcvf sqldata.tar *.sql
cd /home/<username>/db_backup/
perl emailsql.pl
```

next i created a php mail file which sends this zipped file to my email which i named "mail.php"

side note: i used a no-reply@domain.co.za address for the from and reply to address as as its going to myself. edit accordingly.

```
<?php
$to = '<enter email to send to>';
$subject = 'SQL Backup' . date('r', time());
$random_hash = md5(date('r', time()));
$headers = "From: <from address>\r\nReply-To: <reply to address>";
$headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\"";
$attachment= chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents('sqldata/sqldata.tar')));
ob_start();
?>

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>--

--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
Content-Type: application/x-tar; name="sqldata.tar" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
Content-Disposition: attachment 

<?php echo $attachment; ?>
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>-- 

<?php
$message = ob_get_clean();
$mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
?>
```

Then all i did was create a cron job to first run the 'sqlbackup.sh' file to create the zip, then depending on the size of the file, create a cron job to run the 'mail.php' file. I run my mail.php file an hour after the zip config.

if you want to add a message to the email, visit [THIS LINK](http://webcheatsheet.com/php/send_email_text_html_attachment.php#attachment) and add the code accordingly into the area after 'ob_start(); ?>'

Hope this helps.